# What are the parameters create_constraint and name for, in Boolean type in sqlalchemy (python)?

Tags: python, parameters, sqlalchemy, boolean

In the [documentation of sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html) I read:

```
class sqlalchemy.types.Boolean(create_constraint=True, name=None)
```

> A bool datatype.
>
> Boolean typically uses BOOLEAN or
>   SMALLINT on the DDL side, and on the
>   Python side deals in True or False.
>
> Parameters:    create_constraint –
>   defaults to True. If the boolean is
>   generated as an int/smallint, also
>   create a CHECK constraint on the table
>   that ensures 1 or 0 as a value. name –
>   if a CHECK constraint is generated,
>   specify the name of the constraint.

I want to use this type in a declarative way, but I want to understand the parameter descripton first. **What is meant by `create_constraint` and `name` and what do they do?** English is not my natural tong and my knowledge about databases is limited, so thanks for any hints.

What I need is something like:

```
query_status = Column(Boolean, default = False) # Hope the syntax for default value is correct.
```

What would this mean:

```
query_status = Column(Boolean, default = False, create_constraint=True, name='some_name')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `query_status = Column(Boolean, default = False)` # Hope the syntax for default value is correct.

yep

> create_constraint = If the boolean is generated as an int/smallint, also create a CHECK constraint on the **table** that ensures 1 or 0 as a value

it deals on the database level (DDL). It creates a [`check constraint`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Constraint) to make sure the value stays as int/smallint **if** it 's generated as a int/smallint in the database

the `name` argument is the name for that `check constraint`.

Well, Im just rephrasing the definition. I hope you understand

Comment: The Wikipedia Link was exactly what I needed. I thought of `CHECK CONSTRAINTS` as a magical SQLAlchemy thing, but it seems to be a common database thing. Thanks a lot for bringing light into this!